# React-router TypeError: _this.props.history is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router with react js and i following their documentation but facing this error

while compiling it shows the error,

```
TypeError: _this.props.history is undefined
```

this is my index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>

    </Route>
  </Router>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and this is my App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            headerText: "Props from Header.",
            contentText: "Props from content."
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Where from did you call it?

Comment: I Used Router in index.js file and you can see this from the code.

Answer (score 39):

This is because things changed in React Router starting with 4.0.0. You should now use `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom` package when you were using `browserHistory`. So your code will looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/" component={ App }/>
    </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Of course, you'll need to install `react-router-dom` first.

Also note that if you're using more than one `Route` element, you'll have to use a `Switch` as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43690296/1486118).

Answer (score 16):

For me the solution was to change

1) component as child

```
<Route path="/path">
 <MyComponent/>
</Route>
```

to

2) component as the "component" prop

```
<Route path="/path" component={MyComponent}>
</Route>
```

In both ways it renders, so it was very confusing for me, in [examples](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) they provide code as in first example.
(I used the version 5.1.2  of the "react-router-dom" package at the moment).

**Update**

You can also use this way (for child components (children of "MyComponent") works only this one)

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

const componentClassWithHistory = withRouter(ChildComponent);
export {componentClassWithHistory as ChildComponent};
```

or for default export

```
export default withRouter(ChildComponent)
```

or for typescript

```
const componentClassWithHistory = (withRouter(ChildComponent as any) as any);
export {componentClassWithHistory as ChildComponent};
```

Source: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: For functional components is better to use [useHistory](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) hook;

Comment: Same here but I wanted to keep my components as children. You can do that by adding 2 lines to each component to enable withRouter: 1) import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; 2)  export default withRouter(Home); This fixed all my problems. Full details at this guys blog: https://dev.to/kozakrisz/react-router---how-to-pass-history-object-to-a-component-3l0j

Comment: i am working on migrating an old legacy app, and used to hooks. totally forgot about withRouter for child elements. thanks!!!!

Answer (score 7):

Are you using npm? I had the same problem  with "react-router": "^4.0.0" in my package.json. Changing it to "react-router": "^3.0.2" solved my problem.

Comment: "react-router": "^3.0.2" works for me. But don't understand why 4.0.0 is not working.

Comment: Me too) I just compared it with my last working package.json.

Comment: not a good sign when you follow the official tutorial and lesson 1 doesn't work :>

Answer (score 7):

**I have problems with my Form component.**

> this.props.history.push('/') is undefined.
>
> to solve this i've added `import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'`
> And then export default component as:
> `export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(CustomForm));`

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, Input, Button } from "antd";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from "axios";

const FormItem = Form.Item;


class CustomForm extends React.Component {
  
  handleFormSubmit = async (event, requestType, articleID, ) => {
    event.preventDefault();

const postObj = {
  title: event.target.elements.title.value,
  content: event.target.elements.content.value
}

axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
axios.defaults.headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  Authorization: `Token ${this.props.token}`,
};

if (requestType === "post") {
  await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create/", postObj)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status === 201) {
        this.props.history.push(`/`);
      }
    })
} else if (requestType === "put") {
  await axios.put(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${articleID}/update/`, postObj)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        this.props.history.push(`/`);
      }
    })
}


};

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form
          onSubmit={event =>
            this.handleFormSubmit(
              event,
              this.props.requestType,
              this.props.articleID
            )
          }
        >
          <FormItem label="Title">
            <Input name="title" placeholder="Put a title here" />
          </FormItem>
          <FormItem label="Content">
            <Input name="content" placeholder="Enter some content ..." />
          </FormItem>
          <FormItem>
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
              {this.props.btnText}
            </Button>
          </FormItem>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    token: state.token
  };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(CustomForm));
```

*I hope this is useful for someone. I am using Django as a backend*

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly my rookie mistake.

Answer (score 5):

you can use `window.location.href = '/somePath'` as your last resort

Comment: it is working but this method is refreshing my page.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that this.props.history is not defined, because you did not pass the routeProps to the component you want to render.

Change your routes as follows:

```
 <Route path="/home" render={(routeProps) => <Home {...routeProps}/>} />
```

You can also pass other props to the rendered components using this method.

Comment: This just saved me a great deal of trouble after searching for hours. Thanks much.

Comment: @Overcomer happy to help :)

Comment: this actually solved the issue with react-router 5.2.  probably not the best way to do this, but since i'm using older code and upgrading frameworks its just faster

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to use `history` in the functional component and it was undefined because I was trying to access it with `props`.
According to the docs, we need to use `useHistory` hook to access the history. Here is the sample code according to the docs.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
function HomeButton() {


 let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

You can check this [link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) for more understanding.

Comment: V6 has scrapped `useHistory` hook. Instead `useNavigate` hook is used. See this link for more info: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate

Answer (score 3):

This works for me >>>

```
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
```

change the 'react-router' with 'react-router-dom', and Router with BrowserRouter as Router.

Like this >>>

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem when trying to instantiate my own Router rather than using one of the built-in ones, to deal with [an issue of having access to the history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3498#issuecomment-301057248):

**history.js**

```
import { createHashHistory as createHistory } from 'history'

export default createHistory()
```

**root.jsx**

```
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import history from './history'

...

  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/test" component={Test}/>
  </Router>
```

In my case, the trouble was that I had a version of the `history` package locked at v2.1.2, while `react-router` was depending on a v4.x version of `history` in its own dependencies. So the built-in routers instantiated fine using the newer `history`, but when I tried to do it myself I was pulling in the older `history` and getting an incompatible object.

Answer (score 2):

I had something like:

```
<Router>
   <HeaderComponent/>
   <Router exact path="/" component={Home}/>
   <Router path="/auth" component={AuthLayout}/>
   <FooterComponent/>
 </Router>
```

and `AuthLayout` was a component in which I was switching between `SignIn` and `SignUp` components, like below:

```
<div>
  { login ? <SignIn/> : <SignUp/> }
</div>
```

I faced this error of `this.props.history is not a function` inside these components. It was because I hadn't used those components directly inside the router. I had access to `this.props.history` inside the `AuthLayout` and I had to pass it to its children.

So I did it:

```
<div>
  { login ? <SignIn history={this.props.history}/> :  <SignUp history={this.props.history}/> }
</div>
```

and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution works for me in **ReactDOM.render**:

```
 <BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/user" component={User} />
    <Route path="*" component={page404} />
  </Switch>
 </BrowserRouter>
```

It use multiple Routing.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done in the component that is being routed to. In this case, it is App component. Therefore, in App.js, import "createBrowserHistory" and do it as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.history = createBrowserHistory();;

        this.state = {
            headerText: "Props from Header.",
            contentText: "Props from content."
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that if there are any components that you haven't linked to router or any links that is not necessary among your components.

Besides if you have `<Router><Link>...</Link></Router>` in one of your clickable components it might crash your work.

Hope it might help.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue because I was trying to use `props.history.push()` with RRD v6, but v6 has scrapped the `useHistory` hook and instead uses the `useNavigate` hook.

For example:

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('/path');
```

See this link for more info: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate