# React-Router only one child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I keep on getting the error:

> A 'Router' may have only one child element

when using react-router.

I can't seem to figure out why this is not working, since it's exactly like the code they show in their example: [Quick Start](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Editorstore from './Editorstore';
import App from './components/editor/App';
import BaseLayer from './components/baselayer';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

const root = document.createElement('div');
root.id = 'app';
document.body.appendChild(root);

const store = new Editorstore();
const stylelist = ['https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css', 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.33.1/mapbox-gl.css'];

stylelist.map((link) => {
    const a = document.createElement('link');
    a.rel = 'stylesheet';
    a.href = link;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    return null;
});

render((
  <Router>
    <Route exact  path="/" component={BaseLayer} />
    <Route path="/editor" component={App} store={store} />
  </Router>
), document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Comment: Things (`Link`, `Route`) inside `BrowserRouter` need to be wrapped inside a `div`

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You have to wrap your `Route`'s in a `<div>`(or a [`<Switch>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch)).

```
render((
  <Router>
    <Route exact  path="/" component={BaseLayer} />
    <Route path="/editor" component={App} store={store} />
  </Router>
), document.querySelector('#app'));
```

should be

```
render((
  <Router>
    <div>
       <Route exact  path="/" component={BaseLayer} />
       <Route path="/editor" component={App} store={store} />
    </div>
  </Router>
), document.querySelector('#app'));
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/88077/) / [webpackbin](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kfz15YMXr44luMuLWLD)

Comment: Strange. Why is this?

Comment: [`Router`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Router.js#L53) expects `this.props.children` to be `null` or to have length equal to 1

Comment: This isn't working, it just displays both routes in the same place.

Comment: It displays both routes because it is using `div`, you really should use `switch` instead. This makes the route exclusive

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md

Comment: There is a component to do this wrapper: Switch

Comment: It works for me, but it seems like the common way is using Switch. Anyway, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 39):

This is an API change in `react-router` `4.x`. Recommended approach is to wrap `Route`s in a `Switch`: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4131#issuecomment-274171357

Quoting:

Convert

```
<Router>
  <Route ...>
  <Route ...>
</Router>
```

to

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route ...>
    <Route ...>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

You will, of course, need to add `Switch` to your imports:

```
import { Switch, Router, Route } from 'react-router'
```

Comment: I'm getting *Uncaught ReferenceError: Switch is not defined* Error when I'm using Switch

Comment: @NSCoder make sure you're using a `4.x.x` version of `react-router`, and `require` or `import` `Switch` at the top of your module

Comment: if i use switch in **V-4** it say `Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`.`

Answer (score 3):

I Always use Fragment in react web and native ( >= react 16 )

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import { NativeRouter as Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-native'
import Navigation from './components/navigation'    
import HomeScreen from './screens/home'
import { RecipesScreen } from './screens/recipe'

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Navigation />
        <Routes>
          <Fragment>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Route path="/recipes" component={RecipesScreen} />
          </Fragment>
        </Routes>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default Main
```

Answer (score 2):

I put all my `<Route />` tags inside the `<Switch> </Switch>` tag like this.

```
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/' component={App} exact={true} /> 
            <Route path='/form-example' component={FormExample} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

This solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are nesting other components inside the Router you should do like.

```
  <Router>
     <div>
       <otherComponent/>
         <div>
           <Route/>  
           <Route/>
           <Route/>
           <Route/>
         </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Reach Routers](https://reach.tech/router/) make sure the Code looks like this:

```
<Router>
    <Login path="/" />
    <Login path="/login" />
</Router>
```

Including these Components in a `Div` in the case of React Routers will make this work but In Reach Routers, Remove that Div Element.

Answer (score 0):

you can also wrap all your route in a parent route which defaults to index page

```
<Router history={history}>    
   <Route path="/" component={IndexPage}>
      <Route path="to/page" component={MyPage}/>
      <Route path="to/page/:pathParam" component={MyPage}/>
   </Route>    
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using `react-router-dom` package with version `5.0.1` and it works perfectly fine with your code.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router , Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import About from './pages/About';
...

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <ul>
          <li><Link path='/'>Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link path='/about'>About</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my router might be too simple, or there was a change to this rule but was following along a tutorial that mentioned this limitation (*A 'Router' may have only one child element*) and it allowed me to add 3 routes without giving any errors. This is the working code:

```
function render() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      <Route path="/add" component={AddAuthorForm} />
      <Route path="/test" component={test} />
    </BrowserRouter>
    ,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}
```

And this are my dependencies:

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"react-scripts": "3.4.1",
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem occurs when you don't have parent tag before `<Route>`inside `<Router>` so to resolve this problem keep the `<Route>`enclosed in a parent tag such as `<div>` , `<p>` etc.
Example -

```
<Router>
    <p>
       <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
       <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
    </p>
</Router>
```

Comment: Most of the time adding a <p> as routes parent would make it invalid html, as you cannot have a <div> within a <p> for example