# starting a react app raises "A <Router> may have only one child element" at "src/index.js"

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Below is my **index.js** file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import App from './containers/App';
import './styles/bootstrap.css';
import './styles/font-awesome.css';
import './styles/index.css';


ReactDOM.render(

 <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
 </Provider>

 , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

What is causing the error in the title?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-Router only one child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992911/react-router-only-one-child)

Comment: You need to post your app component