# Navigation issues: this.props history appears undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

I am unable to go to another page because `this.props.history` appears undefined. Below is a screenshot of the error that I see. Note that I rendered my welcome component using `this.props.history.push("/welcome")` from the login component and it worked fine then.

[image: screenshot]

This is my App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./Components/Login";
import "./App.css";
import Signup from "./Components/Signup";
import Welcome from "./Components/Welcome";
import RecruiterPage from "./Components/Common/RecriterPage";


function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/welcome" component={Welcome} />
        <Route exact path="/recruiter" component={RecruiterPage} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: [Here is your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857283/react-router-typeerror-this-props-history-is-undefined) I hope that this helps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-router TypeError: \_this.props.history is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857283/react-router-typeerror-this-props-history-is-undefined)

Comment: Because of the division with class "App"(I mean <div className="App"> ), you broke chain between Router and its Routes. So remove this division, and history will be available again.

Comment: @Sercanözen I just moved my `<div className="App">` before `<Router>` but, problem is still there.

Comment: @ZombieChowder I am missing out something maybe as I have tried the solution that you mentioned in your second comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that the component you are trying to navigate from is a child component of a parent component that may or may not have access to history, hence has no access to the history props.

There are two ways to solving this:
1. Pass history as a props from the parent to the child component OR
2. Do this on the said component:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
```

...and when exporting the component, wrap it in withRouter e.g.

```
export default withRouter(ComponentName)
```

Comment: Yes, in this case that would be on ModalButton.js