# Pushing to a dynamic route determined by value controlled by API call

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-router-dom, use-effect

I'm having a problem pushing to a dynamic route. Upon pressing a submit button on a login component, I have an action dispatched that updates the `state.account.id`:

```
export const loginAndGetAccount = credentials => dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: GET_ACCOUNT_START })
    return axios
        .post('https://foodtrucktrackr.herokuapp.com/api/auth/login/operators', credentials)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            dispatch({ type: GET_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS, payload: res.data.id })
            localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

This function, loginAndGetAccount, uses the dispatched actions to update the value in state.account.id like this:

```
case GET_ACCOUNT_START:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true
            }
        case GET_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false,
                account: {
                    id: action.payload
                }
            }
```

Then, I want that value stored in state.account.id to be used to tell the app where to route to. I've tried using a useEffect hook to accomplish this. However, the code inside the useEffect hook just breaks everything; I get an error saying: cannot read property 'push' of undefined. How can I resolve this?

here's the code in App.js:

```
function App(props) {
  const dynamicRoute = `/api/vendor/${props.accountId}`

  useEffect(() => {
    if(props.accountId !== undefined && !props.isLoading) {
      props.history.push(`/api/vendor/${props.accountId}`);
    }
  }, [props.accountId])

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute path={dynamicRoute} component={Dashboard} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    accountId: state.account.id,
    isLoading: state.isLoading
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Comment: You should `console.log(props)` to see if history is the object. If it isn't then your `<App />` isn't wrapped correctly. Take a look at this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/42857283/8817146.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out as much. Ended up just putting the same useEffect hook inside the Login component instead, which is inside the Router. That fixed things. Thanks!

Comment: How is `App` being rendered in the router? Otherwise you could use the `withRouter` HOC or `useHistory` hook to provide the necessary prop or history object.

Comment: I just wrapped a Router around where App is being rendered in index.js

Comment: I see. And are you still experiencing the issue?

Comment: Nope, all is good now. I'm not pushing from the App component anymore. I'm pushing from the Login component, which has access to the history object.