# Conditional routing with ReactRouter in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

```js
class Login extends Component {
  async handle_login(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push('/home')
  }
  render() {
    return (     
      <input type='submit' value='Log in' onSubmit={(e)=>this.handle_login(e)}></input>
      <input type='submit'value='Sign up' onSubmit={(e)=>this.handle_signup(e)}></input>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(Login)
```

```
class App extends Component {
  // app.js

 render() {
 
return (
    <Router> 
      <div className='App' style={{marginTop:'0px'}}>
        <div className='container'>
          <Header></Header>
            
        <Route exact style={{marginTop:'0px'}} path='/' render={(props)=>(
  
   <div style={{display:'flex',justifyContent:'center'}}>
     {/* add  a  background in this div */}
   <Link to='/login' style={{color:'#000000', fontSize:'large',paddingRight:'10px' }}> Login </Link>
   
   <Link to='/' style={{color:'#000000', fontSize:'large' }}> Index </Link>
   </div>


)}></Route>


  <Route exact path='/home' component={Home}></Route>
  <Route  exact path='/login' component={Login}></Route>
  </div>   
  </div>  
       </Router>
  );
 }}
 export default App;
```

I am trying to redirect the 'login' component to the '/home' using withRouter using the aforementioned code, but  running the code does nothing, neither does it throw any error.I have attached the codes of both the home and the login components.

Comment: `console.log(this.props.history)` and let us know if you got anything

Comment: I tried logging history using `console.log(this.props.history) ` in the "handle_login" function, but nothing logged on the console.@BARNOWL

Comment: try doing `console.log(this.props)`

Comment: I tried `console.log(this.props)` in the "handle_login" function, but nothing got rendered on the console.@BARNOWL

Comment: I rendered props using `console.log(this.props)` in the `render` method, and the props do contain the `history` attribute.@BARNOWL

Comment: has this been resolved ?

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I am afraid the doubt has not been resolved yet.@BARNOWL

Comment: you have a link to a repo, or can you make a codesandbox of this ?

Comment: Here's the link to my github repo [ https://github.com/arshagarwal/I_sanatorium ], thanks.@BARNOWL

Comment: [Github Link](https://github.com/arshagarwal/I_sanatorium)

Comment: will look into this. so the issue is you can't be directed the home page ? its a been few days since i looked at this question. Just want to make sure.

Comment: yes, exactly.@BARNOWL

Comment: its.... working for me. im able to login and im directed to home. I made no changes.

Comment: What is the issue that you're having exactly

Comment: I am not redirected to 'home' when the submit button is pressed, could it be due to browser, I am using Chrome on ubuntu?@BARNOWL

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is probably because you forgot your constructor to get the props and [bind your method](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

Update your class to this

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handle_login = this.handle_login.bind(this);
  }
  
  // No "async" need here
  handle_login(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push('/home')
  }
  render() {
    return (     
      <input type='submit' value='Log in' onSubmit={(e)=>this.handle_login(e)}></input>
      <input type='submit'value='Sign up' onSubmit={(e)=>this.handle_signup(e)}></input>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Login)
```

I would also suggest passing your method to the `onSubmit` handle, instead of creating a new function there:

```
<input type='submit' value='Log in' onSubmit={this.handle_login}></input>
```

---

### Update

I also notice that you have 2 inputs of type `submit`, which is not very common. Your action is also in the `onSubmit` and not `onClick`, but you don't have a `<form>` which is usually what triggers the `submit` function.

My suggestion is to review your HTML structure as well and make sure it make sense. For now, try this to at least get your method working:

```
render() {
  // buttons have type="submit" by default, so no need to include that
  return (
    <button value='Log in' onClick={(e)=>this.handle_login(e)}></input>
  );
}
```

There is an interesting discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117639/input-type-submit-vs-button-tag-are-they-interchangeable), as additional reference.

Comment: I tried binding as illustrated, but it didn't work.@BrunoMonteiro

Comment: Even passing the method to `onSubmit` as illustrated didn't work.@BrunoMonteiro

Comment: I updated my answer, please check if that helps. It was too much info for a comment, so it was easier to update the answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I am afraid neither wrapping the input tags in a form element, nor using the button tag as illustrated worked, I reckon there is a problem with the `app.js` file, which I have thus added in the question, could you please have a look?@BrunoMonteiro

Answer (score 0):

@BrunoMonteiro is correct but there is an alternate option for this you can declare your function as arrow function so that you don't have to bind

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  
  handle_login=async(e)=> {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push('/home')
  }
  render() {
    return (     
      <input type='submit' value='Log in' onClick={(e)=>this.handle_login(e)}></input>
      <input type='submit'value='Sign up' onClick={(e)=>this.handle_signup(e)}></input>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Login)
```

also make sure you have access to history property in your props for checking this you can do console.log(this.props) and check whether it has required property or not

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried logging the props, and the props do contain the history property, but am still not able to make the code work.@Anku

Comment: I doubt that you are not getting history property because you are using react-router version 4.0.0 and greater and there are some changes made in version 4.0.0 or greater check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857283/react-router-typeerror-this-props-history-is-undefined and make changes accordingly in route file and see if it works @Arshagarwal

Comment: Actually I am already using `BrowserRouter` by the alias `Router` in the code illustrated in the link you mentioned.@Anku